# Absolute value function definition

Tags: calculus, definition, piecewise-continuity

The standard definition of is $f(x)=\begin{cases}x,& x\geq 0\\-x,&x<0\end{cases}$. I am wondering what the problem is with the definition $f(x)=\begin{cases}x,& x,\geq 0\\-x,&x\leq0.\end{cases}$. Similarly, for piecewise defined functions like $f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x-1, & x\leq 2 \\
      -3+4x-x^2, & x> 2
   \end{cases}$ I remember having seen authors using the definition $f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x-1, & x\leq 2 \\
      -3+4x-x^2, & x\geq 2
   \end{cases}$ (see for instance Wiki's lemma for piecewise functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise). Is there a difference between the two? Is the former preferable?

Comment: Two ways of saying the same thing, since $-0=0$.

Comment: They are emphatically the same function. You have to think very slightly harder with the second definition, because you need to be sure the two definitions agree at $x=2$ (or $x=0$). But as long as you are sure of that, the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: There is a *third* definition: $|x|:=\begin{cases}x&x>0\\0&x=0\\-x&x<0\end{cases}$. No ambiguity and no asymmetry (but more cases to consider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining a function piecewise like this, it is a simple courtesy to your readers to make sure that all your cases are mutually exclusive. That way, they don't have to check that the function takes the same value on the intersection of two or more different cases, which is required for your definition to be valid.